# INSERT statement with existing records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I was wondering if it is possible to do an insert statement with records that already exist. For example:

```
insert into tbl(item_name, item_price) values(select item_name, item_price from tbl where id = 5)
```

Say id is an auto incrementing pk.

When I try something similar to this, I'm getting errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Am I missing something, or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout this article: [Adding Rows by Using INSERT and SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/ms188263.aspx)

Anyway the right way is the following:

```
insert into tbl(item_name, item_price) 
select item_name, item_price 
  from tbl 
 where id = 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
insert into tbl(item_name, item_price) select item_name, item_price from tbl where id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

A subquery is possible in MySQL, but if you're doing it like this then your database is probably not normalized properly, and a design change would be your best move.

Here's the syntax for a subquery: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html